# MDX CurrentMember evaluation on Calculated Members - Weird Result

Tags: mdx

I'm using SQL Server Analysis Services.

I have a calculated member that, for now, just does this:

```
[MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME")
```

Previously, I had just written `[MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy].CurrentMember.UniqueName`. They should be the same anyway.

Now, I used SQL Profiler to get ahold of the query my application issues. For a simple calculated member in `[MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy]` that just sums to different members, say with IDs 401 and 402, I get this result:

```
[MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy].&[401][MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy].&[402]
```

In other words, it is as if AS evaluates the underlying members and concatenates the results, rather than giving me the unique name of the calculated member...

The REALLY strange thing to me is that when I take the original query, and prepend the following:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[GiveMeCalculatedMemberUniqueName]
AS
(
[MyDimension].[MyOnlyHierarchy].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME")
)
```

...rest of query

I get the CORRECT results using this second measure! The context is the same (to me at least). Everything is the same... Yet the measure declared in the project file gives a different result than this inline calculated member.

What's going on here? Note, I've redeployed 10000 times, and I've checked the actual definition in the cube on the server and everything. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculations are evaluated based on solve order. may be because you moved it down and it was how the solve order was supposed to work it gives you correct result . I have a little blog on solve order [here](http://codeperfect.wordpress.com/2009/10/02/how-can-solve-order-effect-your-mdx-calculations/) but there are many more articles on internet.

HTH

Comment: Yeah, this seems to have been the case. But the result was just so strange I couldn't figure it out at first. Will read your blog entry.

Answer (score 0):

Funny... I've been sitting for about 2-3 hours with this, exploring every thought; then, after I post this question I decide to try one more thing:

**move the calulated member definition to the bottom of the calculated members script file in the project.**

This now gives the correct result.